# No Repeat Tag on Bootstrap Jumbotron causes image to disappear

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the background image in my bootstrap 4 jumbotron responsive, but when I add the no-repeat tag the image disappears from the site. Any advice you have for making the image responsive and making the image show up without repeating on mobile would be much appreciated! Thank you so much in advance!

Katie

css:

```
#sixthHomejt{
        background-image: url(homejt.png) no-repeat;
        background-size:100%;
        color:darkgrey;
        height:550px;
         }
```

html:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="sixthHomejt">
<div class="container">
<h1 class="display-3" style="text-align:center; padding-top:1%;">Columbia 
 Middle School</h1>
<p class="lead" style="text-align:center;font-size:200%; ">Sixth Grade</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using distinct configuration values assign   and use quotes  around image url name

```
  #sixthHomejt{
    background-image: url('./homejt.png'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    color:darkgrey;
    height:550px;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to get the whole thing to scale for mobile? Now it just looks squished

Comment: for the correct ration between widh and height .. try assing a proper  width  and work on min-height ,  min-width